# tkz-euclide drawing compass-mark like for Arc construction

Tags: tkz-euclide, arc

i would like the arcs to appeared only on points I and J
(with dash or not like in the manual example) but not as on the first tex-output.  the long lines of circles are not needed. i just would like to show how to get I and J points to determine the Cm point on triangle.

here is my code :

```
   \documentclass{standalone}
   \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

    %triangle
    \tkzDefPoint(4,2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(8,3){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(6,5){C}
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)

    %point Cm
    %intersect circles
    \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{I}{J}
    %median line
    \tkzDrawLine[color=green!50!black,dashed, add=.04 and .04](I,J)

    %test arcs (type compass)
    \tkzSetUpCompass[color=blue] %blue don't show up :-(
    \tkzDrawArc[delta=10](A,B)(I)
    \tkzDrawArc[delta=8](B,I)(A)
    \tkzDrawArc[delta=10](B,A)(J)
    \tkzDrawArc[delta=8](A,J)(B)
    
    %label points
    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below right](B) 
    \tkzLabelPoints[above right=2mm](C)
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left, red](I){$I$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right, red](J){$J$}
    \tkzDrawPoints(I,J)

    %spec signs
    \node[magenta] at ($(A)!0.25!(B)$){$/$};
    \node[magenta] at ($(A)!0.75!(B)$){$/$};    
    
    %median line C-Cm
    \coordinate (Cm) at ($1/2*(A)+1/2*(B)$);
    \tkzDrawPoint(Cm)
    \tkzDrawLine[dashed, color=red, add=.1 and .15](C,Cm)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below right=2mm, magenta](Cm){$C_m$}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather then `\tkzDrawArc` you need to use `\tkzCompass`, `\tkzCompass[length=1](A,I)` add an arc of compass with length of 1, the center is `A` and passes through `I`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

%triangle
\tkzDefPoint(4,2){A}
\tkzDefPoint(8,3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(6,5){C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)

%point Cm
%intersect circles
\tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{I}{J}
%median line
\tkzDrawLine[color=green!50!black,dashed, add=.04 and .04](I,J)

%test arcs (type compass)
\tkzSetUpCompass[color=blue] %blue don't show up :-(
\tkzCompass[length=1](A,I)
\tkzCompass[length=1](B,I)
\tkzCompass[length=1](A,J)
\tkzCompass[length=1](B,J)    
%\tkzDrawArc[delta=10](A,B)(I)
%\tkzDrawArc[delta=8](B,I)(A)
%\tkzDrawArc[delta=10](B,A)(J)
%\tkzDrawArc[delta=8](A,J)(B)

%label points
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B) 
\tkzLabelPoints[above right=2mm](C)
\tkzLabelPoint[above left, red](I){$I$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below right, red](J){$J$}
\tkzDrawPoints(I,J)

%spec signs
\node[magenta] at ($(A)!0.25!(B)$){$/$};
\node[magenta] at ($(A)!0.75!(B)$){$/$};    

%median line C-Cm
\coordinate (Cm) at ($1/2*(A)+1/2*(B)$);
\tkzDrawPoint(Cm)
\tkzDrawLine[dashed, color=red, add=.1 and .15](C,Cm)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right=2mm, magenta](Cm){$C_m$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: damn o_0 ! thank you so much.

Comment: @FannyMae You are welcome.